# Is the subset of $\ell^1$ where the $k$th coordinate is $0$ or $2^{-k}$ perfect?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I've encountered the following problem:

Determine whether or not the following set is perfect in a metric space $(X,d)$: $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k} \right\}$ in $(\ell_1, \|\cdot\|_1)$.

The problem is that I don't really understand this notation. First of all, how does the sequence above exactly work? I'm reading it as follows:

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left\{0, \frac{1}{2^k} \right\}=\left\{0, \frac12\right\}\times \left\{0, \frac14\right\}\times\dots \times \left\{0, \frac1{2^k} \right\}\times\dots$$

But what kind of a sequence is this? How does the norm on this sequence work? Also, isn't it true by definition that sequences in $\ell_1$ have the metric $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: Point is that you can choose one of two numbers for each position in the sequence. One element in the set is $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ and another is $(1,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{8},\ldots)$, and so on. This is not just a single sequence, but uncountably infinitely many sequences.

Comment: Another way to think of this set is as the collection of all functions $x:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ such that $x(k)\in\left\{0,\frac{1,2^k}\right\}$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: The set is perfect. Indeed, let $(a_n)$ be any sequence from $\ell_1$ but not from the set.
Then there exists an index $N$ such that $a_N\ne 1,\frac 1{2^N}$. Pick a number 
$0<\varepsilon<\min\left\{|a_N|,\left|a_N\frac 1{2^N} \right| \right\}$.
If a sequence $(b_n)$ belongs to $\ell_1$ and $d((b_n),(a_n))<\varepsilon$
then $b_N\ne 1,\frac 1{2^N}$, so the sequence $(b_n)$ does not belong to the set.
Thus the set is closed.

Comment: Let $(a_n)$ be any sequence of it and $\varepsilon>0$ be any number.
Pick a natural number $N$ such that $\frac 2{2^N}<\varepsilon$ and a sequence $(b_n)\ne (a_n)$ from the set such that $b_n=a_n$ for each $n\le N$. Then $d((b_n),(a_n))<\varepsilon$. Thus $(a_n)$ is not an isolated point of the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, this is the set $C$ of all sequences $x$ such that for each $k$, the entry $x_k$ is either $0$ or $2^{-k}$. The metric is inherited from the space $\ell^1$, which already has a metric induced by $\|\cdot \|_1$ norm.

The set $C$ is

- *Closed*. Indeed, if $y\notin C$, then there is $k$ such that $y_k$ is neither $0$ nor $2^{-k}$. Hence, any sequence $z$ sufficiently close to $y$ will also have $z_k\notin \{0,2^{-k}\}$. This shows the complement of $C$ is open.
- *Totally bounded*. For any $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $2^{-N}<\epsilon$, and this means $\sum_{k>N}2^{-k}<\epsilon$. So we can group the sequences in $C$ into $2^N$ subsets according to the first $N$ entries of the sequence; each subset has diameter $< \epsilon$.
- *Without isolated points*. If $x\in C$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is $k$ such that $2^{-k}<\epsilon$. Flip the $k$th entry of $x$ from $0$ to $2^{-k}$ or back, and we get $y\in C$ such that $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$.

In a Banach space, closed and totally bounded implies compact (since a closed subset of a complete metric space is complete).